# Insert shell output into vim with many quotes

Tags: vim

I have troubles consolidating this shell command:

```
uuidgen | tr -d '\n' | awk '{printf("\"%s\"", $0);}'
```

into Vimscript like this:

```
:command UUID execute "normal! \"=system('...')\<CR>p"
```

My current attempt is:

```
:command UUID execute "normal! \"=system('uuidgen | tr -d \'\n\' | awk \'{printf(\"\"%s\"\", $0);}\'')\<CR>p"
```

Which returns `Unknown mark` when I run the command. I assume I ended up in escaping hell and don't know how to recover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like this can be done simpler with `systemlist()`

```
command! UUID put='\"'.systemlist('uuidgen')[0].'\"'
nnoremap <key> "='"'.systemlist('uuidgen')[0].'"'<cr>p
inoremap <key> <c-r>='"'.systemlist('uuidgen')[0].'"'<cr>
```

If you didn't mind `'` then you can use the `string()` function which would be even easier.

For more help see:

```
:h systemlist()
:h string()
```

Comment: This is great. Do you know why the put command still inserts it onto the new line?

Comment: `:put` is line-wise as are most (all?) ex commands. See `:h linewise`. `:put` is a common way to "force" a register to be linewise.

Comment: With the key mapping it works great. I am curious, is there an alternative command to put so that if I just enter :UUID I get the same behavior as just pressing the key?

Comment: Commands are line based so making `:UUID` charcter-wise would be "weird". You could do this with `:normal`, e.g. `command! UUID execute "normal a\<c-r>='\"'.systemlist('uuidgen')[0].'\"'\<cr>"`

Comment: Then I'll stick to the idiom.

Answer (score 0):

escaping hell... ;-]

```
escape('uuidgen | tr -d ''\n'' | awk ''{printf("\"%s\"", $0);}'')','\\/.*$^~[]')
```

Note **double single quotes** in first part. Second part is universal snippet for escaping.

```
escape('string','\\/.*$^~[]')
```

From here it should by easy